# How to calculate the average from a count result in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the following tables:

VISITS:
vid,
pid,
date

PATIENT:
pid,
pname,
age,
gender

so i want to know the average of visits for each patient.
I have tried to solve it so hard, but still can't get it done!
hope someone can help me out.

Comment: What SQL have you tried so far?

Comment: Average per (day, week, month, year...) what?

Comment: average per month! :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us what you tried and post the error as well so we can pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by counting the total number of visits and dividing by the total number of patients.

```
select (select count(*) from visits) / (select 1.0*count(*) from patients) as AvgVisitsPerPatient
```

Note the following:

- The `1.0*` is needed to change the count to a decimal.  SQL Server does integer division on integers.
- The use of the `patients` table.  Some patients may not have any visits, and they are included.
- The use of nested subqueries in the `select`.  This is allowed.

EDIT:

You do not have enough information to calculate averages for a given unit of time.  Although you have the date for a visit, you don't have a date for the patient, so you don't know who the population is at any given point of time.

Comment: thats great! and thanks for commenting, and post a solution!! but how can i use the AVG function? lets say a patient's got 3 visits so i want to know the average...

Comment: @appleduardo . . . You would need a subquery and that is not the best way to answer this question.  Kind of funky.  You want an average.  SQL has `AVG()`.  And yet the best way is to do the calculation as a total divided by a count.

Comment: why a subquery is not the best way? 
i just that im getting started with databases, and i'd say theres no need to calculate this with AVG(), but my teacher wants me to do it this way :/ so ...

Comment: Minus 1.  As per Charles's answer, the average number of visits per patient simply does not exist.

Comment: @DanBracuk . . . I think that is a willful misinterpretation of the question.  The difference between ""he average of visits for each patient" and "the average of visits for all patients" is probably lost on most non-native speakers of English.

Answer (score -1):

The Average number of visits for each patient is not possible.  There is only one scalar value for the total number of visits for any single patient.  You cannot average that.  You could average the number of visits for all patients, or the number of visits per month for each patient, but you cannot average a set of values when there is only one value in the set.  (or to be technically accurate, you can average a single value, but the average is the same as the value because the count is one.)

Average number of visits for all patients =
  Sum of visits / number of patients

```
Select Avg(Count(*))
From Visits
Group By pid
```

Average number of visits per month for each patient

```
Select p.pid, p.pname, 
   Avg(z.monthVisits) AvgMonthlyVisits
From (Select Pid, Count(*) monthVisits
      From table
      Group By Pid, Month(date)) z
   join Patient p
       on p.pid = z.pid
Group By p.pid
```